# Object embed not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

Alright so I'm trying to embed an swf file with this code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="480">
    <param name="FlashContent" value="http://www.drudexflash.com/flash/Vegetard_3.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <embed src="http://www.drudexflash.com/flash/Vegetard_3.swf" quality="high" width="640" height="480" 
    name="Vegetard - Dragonzball P" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
```

it seems to work fine on every browser except for internet explorer, flash content like youtube seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer uses the object tag. Try setting a different classid than the one you have. You can see a working version I set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/cYrFx/2/