# Plone Dexterity Type to Embed SWF File Internet Explorer Not Working

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

Using Dexterity on Plone 4.2 I have created a custom type which enables the user to upload .ogg, .mp4, .webm and .swf files, these are then displayed using a `<video>` element.

I have run into a problem in which it seems Internet Explorer doesn't know how to get hold of the **swf** file.

Below is the view for my type:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/ogg_video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/ogg_video_file/${context/ogg_video_file/filename}"
    type="video/ogg"
  />
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/video_file/${context/video_file/filename};"
    type="video/mp4"
  />
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/webm_video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/webm_video_file/${context/webm_video_file/filename}"
      type="video/webm"
  />
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553549D43"
    width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie"
      tal:attributes="value string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/swf_video_file/${context/swf_video_file/filename}"/>
    <param name="flashvars" value=""/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="allowfullscreenaccess" value="true"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <embed width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
      tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/swf_video_file/${context/swf_video_file/filename}"/>
  </object>f]-->
  </object>      
</video>
```

Everything works as expected until Internet Explorer 8 or below is loaded up, obviously it doesn't support the `<video>` element so it would then render the `<object>` element, however it doesn't seem to find or play the swf file.

I have tried:

- Moving `<object>` outside of `<video>`
- Using [SWFObject.js](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api)
- Testing out the same code but with hardcoded swf files and no TALES **(this works in IE)**
- Separating each element to see all 3  tags (`<video>`, `<object>`, `<embed>`) to make sure one of the tags isn't being overridden by another **(they still will not work in IE)**
- Following the output paths in the HTML to the SWF files in Inter Explorer **(this works and I am prompted to download the swf file)**
- Taking note of the answer to a [non-Plone related but similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268152/object-embed-not-working-in-internet-explorer) **(Unfortunately this didn't help in this instance)**

So I know my code *works*, but I can't figure out why I am not seeing my video. When I right click where the video *should be* in IE, I only see:

```
Movie not loaded...
About Adobe Flash Player 10...
```

If you could shed some light on my situation it would be greatly appreciated.

**More information will follow as I attempt to carry on fixing this myself, I am slightly suspicious of my code**

### Update

It seems after modifying the `<object>` code to the following:

```
  <object
    width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    tal:attributes="data string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/swf_video_file/${context/swf_video_file/filename}"
    id="swf_video">
    <param name="movie"
      tal:attributes="value string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/swf_video_file/${context/swf_video_file/filename}"/>
    <param name="flashvars" value=""/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="allowfullscreenaccess" value="true"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
  </object>
```

Internet Explorer seems to download the flash movie but not play it. (I can see the little message "1 item remaining" while the page is loading, and this takes quite a while to go away, I assume this means it's downloading the video but still not playing it. Right clicking where the video is still shows me the same `Movie not loaded...` message

The box that I see which disappears as soon as the item has finished downloading:
[image: The box that I see which disappears as soon as the item has finished downloading]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) to perhaps give me a more 'finished' experience for Internet Explorer *(instead of a merely embedded swf file)* when I stumbled across a handy generator:

http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/

After a bit of TALES-ifying it does exactly what I want.

Code for anyone else struggling with a similar problem:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/webm_video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/webm_video_file/${context/webm_video_file/filename}"
    type="video/webm"
  />
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/video_file/${context/video_file/filename};"
    type="video/mp4"
  />
  <source src=""
    tal:condition="context/ogg_video_file"
    tal:attributes="src string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/ogg_video_file/${context/ogg_video_file/filename}"
    type="video/ogg"
  />          
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="320" height="240">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" 
      tal:attributes="value string:config={'playlist':[{'url':'${context/absolute_url}/@@download/video_file/${context/video_file/filename}','autoPlay':true}]}"/>
        <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below"></span>
    </object>
</video>
```

The code uses HTML5 for all browsers that support it but falls back to [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)'s flash implementation for older ones. It looks like it uses the `<param name="movie"/>` tag to pull in the flash player and then the `<param name="flashVars"/>` tag to pass the URL of the video file to FlowPlayer.